# Handle Dalli::RingError - No server available in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, memcached, heroku, sinatra

I have a Sinatra application running on Heroku which makes use of Dalli to enable memcached support. Occasionally, the memcached server fails to respond, and I get the following:

```
Dalli::RingError - No server available
```

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I chose to handle this by explicitly ignoring the error, as there is no reason why my app functionality should fail if the caching component is down.  You could certainly implement a log statement or whatever you want, but I chose to do nothing.

I created my own Cache class and use that to insulate my domain code from Dalli.  Here is the relevant part:

```
def Cache.get(key)
  Configuration.dalliClient.get(key)    
rescue Dalli::RingError
  nil
end
```

Comment: Interesting.. Might it be a good idea to set some kind of flag - cache is down - which gets tested each time some action takes place, so we could start using the cache once the connection has been established?

Comment: You could set a flag, although I chose not to do that because it would involve an extra statement to check the flag on every Cache usage, and you'd also have to figure out a way to know once memcached was back if you weren't going to call it every time. A log statement or some way of informing the admin memcached is down seems more appropriate.

Comment: It may be worth noting that in certain situations, this is not a good idea.
If the server is using extensive caching to stay alive, then allowing the server to live and burn out instead of simply dying when the cache server is down could be less cost efficient if you pay for your usage of the server